# SwiftUI - Ignoring async call-back and show next view issue

Tags: swift, swiftui

I made [30 seconds video](https://youtu.be/q0HVcYASYjE) of issue I am describing below:

I have `UserService` class which is a part of SceneDelegate and injected it to my first displayed `LoginView`:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var userService = UserService() 

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        let contentView = LoginView().environmentObject(userService)
...
```

In the LoginView I have navigation link which I trigger via async callback programatically:

```
NavigationLink(destination: WelcomeView(), isActive: $showWelcomeView) { EmptyView() }
```

When I get user from the `userService` I show WelcomeView

```
struct WelcomeView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var userService: UserService

var body: some View {
                VStack {
                    CircleImage(image: userService.user.image!)
                        .offset(y: -220)
                        .frame(height: 140)
                        .frame(width: 140)
...
```

as you see my userService is an `@EnvironmentObject`.

First time I show `WelcomeView` from navigation link all works good, but when I pop back to `LoginView` and login again to push `WelcomeView` I see this error:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value:
```

[image]

By some reason my `userService.user.image` became `nil` after I pop back to previous Login view and push Welcome view again.

Then I tried to debug it and found out that somehow my async call back here is ignored. You can see I make two async calls I've added a comment below where I never get callback for the second run:

```
func getUser(with email: String, completion: @escaping (UserFetchResult) -> Void) {

        let findUsers:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
        findUsers.whereKey("email",  equalTo: email)
        findUsers.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
            if error == nil {
                guard let firstFoundUser = objects?.first as? PFUser else {
                    print("Get users error")
                    completion(.failure)
                    return
                }

                self.user = User(pfUser: firstFoundUser)
                // IGNORED THIS CALL AND DISPLAY WelcomeView without waiting completion handler.
                self.user.avatar?.getDataInBackground(block: { (data, error) in

                    if error == nil {
                        if let unwrappedData = data {
                            if let unwrappedUIImage = UIImage(data: unwrappedData) {
                                self.user.image = Image(uiImage: unwrappedUIImage)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if self.user.image == nil {
                        self.user.image = Image("ManPlaceholderAvatar")
                    }

                    completion(.success(data: self.user))
                })

            } else {
                print("Get users error")
                completion(.failure)
            }
        }
    }
```

You can check debug details in this [video](https://youtu.be/EtRXQE-z1ek).

Comment: I have different question - why getUser should be called at all second time if the user already fetched & image retrieved? I think it design issue here - there have not be such refetch for just constructed user at all, no?

Comment: @Asperi thanks for your comments! I have user fetched but it's kind of a first sing in check when we can identify that we have this email in the system actually. Welcome screen just needed for entering password if desired user was found by first request. Anyway your thoughts started me thinking that's probably the issue I faced is not with SwiftUI but with Parse. Looks like `self.user.avatar?.getDataInBackground` will be never invoked because it's cached already. But still can't understand how navigation works ignoring completion handler.

Comment: @Asperi I've created a public [repo](https://github.com/matrosovDev/swiftui) if you have time to take a look. there are just two Views. So for the first time all works good, but second time the WelcomeView pushed without waiting completion handler actually (I mean if we pop back and push again one more time). I've added print command.

Comment: @Asperi looks like when I pop back to login screen from welcome the welcome screen still exist. and when I try to update observable property it lead to this update issue.

Comment: @Asperi looks like I found the issue with deallocating WelcomeView. This post not so clear then as it's not connected to actually async call but to allocating and deallocating issue. I've posted new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61448125/swiftui-pop-back-in-navigation-stack-does-not-deallocate-a-view). I would like to close this question if you don't mind. thanks for help.