# SwiftUI - Pop back in navigation stack does not deallocate a view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios-navigationview

I would like to start by highlighting my views hierarchy. I just have `FindUserView` and `WelcomeView`.

`FindUserView` is used for retrieving users from the server if the entered email exists. If so, then it automatically redirects me to the next `WelcomeView` where I can enter password and login.

I've created a [repo here](https://github.com/matrosovDev/swiftui) and a video [SwiftUI - Pop back does not deallocate view](https://youtu.be/tXoES1b2oR4)

My `FindUserView`: ---------------------------- and `WelcomeView`:

[image] ----------------- [image]

By pressing NEXT button on `FindUserView` I fetch a user from the database:

```
func fetchUser(with email: String) {
        userService.getUser(with: email) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(_):
                self.showActivityIndicator = false
                self.showingAlert = false
                self.showWelcomeView = true
                break
            case .failure:
                self.showingAlert = true
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

I use `NavigationView` and programatically show `WelcomeView` by changing `showWelcomeView` state above:

```
NavigationLink(destination: WelcomeView(), isActive: $showWelcomeView) { EmptyView() }
```

Now I am on welcome view `WelcomeView`.

But when I press this button and pop back, my `WelcomeView` still exists.

[image]

As I use `@EnvironmentObject` with observable property state I see how it reflects to the view which is already dismissed. Is this correct behaviour? Or do I need to dealloc `WelcomeView` somehow? Does it lead to memory leaks?

I am a bit worry as in `UIKit` when you pop back in navigation stack the view controller it is deallocated by `UINavigationController` by removing view controller from the array automatically. How to pop back correctly in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it is not clear if it is defect or not - SwiftUI views are values, so there is no *dealloc* thing for them. It looks like `NavigationView` just keeps something like *lastView* variable until it is replaced with another one. Maybe worth submitting feedback to Apple.

Meanwhile here is solution that allows to defer real destination view creation until exactly `NavigationLink` tapped and cleanup it (w/ any related resources, like view model) when view is removed from stack by Back button.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

Helper proxy view presenter:

```
struct LinkPresenter<Content: View>: View {
    let content: () -> Content

    @State private var invlidated = false
    init(@ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if self.invlidated {
                EmptyView()
            } else {
                content()
            }
        }
        .onDisappear { self.invlidated = true }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
NavigationLink(destination: LinkPresenter { WelcomeView() }, 
    isActive: $showWelcomeView) { EmptyView() }
```

Comment: ok got it thank you! let me try your solution, also I submit an issue to Apple. let's see what's they will comment.

Comment: Apple relied to me with next (not sure I understood): The data needs to control whether or not ongoing work is happening. Looking at the code, the state in WelcomeView seems wrong. showActivityIndicator is set to true when the fetch starts, but nothing sets it to false. That property shouldn’t be state of the view but should be a property of the object doing the fetching. The activity indicator will then stop when the fetch stops and the view won’t consume any resources when idle.