# SwiftUI - triggered breakpoints twice

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to figure out why a breakpoint triggered just once for the first time I used my app and when I did the same steps one more time the breakpoints triggered twice for the same line of code, nothing changed on runtime I just used navigation forward and back. I demo this issue with a comment on my video below. It's 5 minutes video with explanation, but you will see the issue in 2 minutes:

here is a link to a video I made
https://youtu.be/s3fqJ4YhQEc

If you don't want to watch a video I will add a code at the bottom of the question:

here is a link to a repo I used to record a video: https://github.com/matrosovDev/SwiftUINavigatioPopBackIssue

I am also use Apple Feedback Assistant, so guys help me with this as well. I assumed that there is something with deallocating view that was not deallocated in a right way but they answered with this:

> There is no notion of “deallocating” structs in Swift. SwiftUI manages
>   view lifetimes. If you’re writing code that somehow depends on the
>   existance or non-existance of a particular View at a particular point
>   in time, that code is wrong.
>
> What leads you to believe that the SecondView isn’t “deallocated”?
>   The code that leads you to that conclusion is making incorrect
>   assumptions about the SwiftUI view lifecycle.

Anyway you may see on the video breakpoints triggered twice and even before I actually showing `SecondView`.

Code example:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var simpleService: SimpleService
    @State var showSecondView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.downloadImageFromURL()
                }) {
                    Text("Next")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 40, bottom: 20, trailing: 40))
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }

                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(), isActive: $showSecondView) { EmptyView() }
            }
        }
    }

    func downloadImageFromURL() {
        simpleService.image = nil
        if let url = URL(string: "https://placebear.com/200/300") {
            simpleService.downloadImage(from: url) { (image) in
                self.showSecondView = true
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CircleImage: View {
    var image: Image
    var body: some View {
        image
            .resizable()
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
            .shadow(radius: 10)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var simpleService: SimpleService

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            CircleImage(image: simpleService.image!) // Called twice next time I visit SecondView
                .frame(height: 140)
                .frame(width: 140)
        }.onAppear(perform: fetch)
    }

    private func fetch() {
        print(Date())
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it the same to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61448125/swiftui-pop-back-in-navigation-stack-does-not-deallocate-a-view?

Comment: @Asperi yea almost the same and thank you for answer on it. but I still have a long conversation with Apple about it. And in your example from the link you've just provided when we force invalidate view we actually replace it with an empty view. So when I navigate to the third view or 4th view the view I force invalidated will be empty every time I hit back button. So which is ok if I need to solve crash issue specified there.

Comment: @Asperi this question is more about invocation breakpoints twice and is more connected to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386069/swiftui-ignoring-async-call-back-and-show-next-view-issue) I answered before. So anyway I still don't understand why the code `CircleImage(image: simpleService.image!)` called twice when I play with navigation (go back and then again forward). You suggested smth about that SwiftUI somehow store next view or kind of that. But it's still kind of magic for me.

Comment: @Asperi, Apple support also saying that probably I use smth wrong, but I don't see any ugly code definition in my repo, if there is smth why they did not point me to it. I just want to figure out why it called twice why it called even before the view is shown for the second time I navigate to the view that's my question and I am a bit disappointed still (

anyway thank you for any you answers! I appreciate this!